# Pull the metrics out of couchbase like QPS, gets/sec etc and plot them on the graph as Couchbase UI does?

Tags: couchbase, membase

Pull the metrics out of couchbase like QPS, gets/sec etc and plot them on the graph as Couchbase UI does .. As I have a personal program which continuosly can poll couchbase for all this data and plot them on a graph .. .

IS there an API call I can make to fetch these metrics for a specific bucket/server and plot them on the graph using my own program??

Comment: I`m having trouble in using cbstats it says command not found on bash [link](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-monitoring-nodestats.html)

Answer (score 1):

The location of cbstats is documented here:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.1.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbstats.html

Also you can use the REST API to get some stats:
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.1.0/couchbase-admin-restapi.html